# How to recover sparse circulant matrix based on its partial eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, optimization, diagonalization, sparse-matrices, circulant-matrices

Suppose we have a right circulant matrix ($n \times n$)
$$
C=
\begin{bmatrix} 
    c_0 & c_{n-1} & c_{n-2} & \cdots &  c_1\\
    c_1 & c_0 & c_{n-1} & \cdots & c_2\\
    c_2 & c_1 & c_0 &\cdots & c_3\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots&\vdots \\
    c_{n-1} & c_{n-2} & c_{n-3} &\cdots & c_0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the first $\ell$, where $\ell \ll n$, elements of the first column of $C$ is non-zero, namely,
$$
   \begin{bmatrix} 
    c_0 & c_1 & c_2 & \cdots &  c_{n-1}\\
   \end{bmatrix}^T
   =
   \begin{bmatrix} 
    c_0 & c_1 & c_2 & \cdots &  c_{l-1} & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}^T
$$

It's well known that circulant matrix can be diagonalized by discrete Fourier transform, namely,
$$
FCF^H=
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \lambda_0 & 0 & \cdots &  0\\
    0 & \lambda_1 &   \cdots & 0\\
    \vdots & \vdots &\ddots&\vdots \\
    0 & 0   &\cdots & \lambda_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $F$ is Fourier matrix ($F_{pq}=e^{-j2\pi\frac{pq}{n}}$), $F^H$ is conjugate matrix of $F$, and $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalues of $C$

If we only have $m$, where $\ell < m < n$, eigenvalues of sparse circulant matrix $C$, how can we recover $C$?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have changed the symbols

Comment: Do you have the eigenvalues with the largest magnitude or any random EVs?

Comment: Do you know to which eigenvectors the known eigenvalues correspond?